# Building a filter with Python & MATLAB, results are not the same

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I want to translate this MATLAB code into Python, I guess I did everything right, even though I didn't get the same results.

MATLAB script:

```matlab
n=2   %Filter_Order
Wn=[0.4 0.6]  %# Normalized cutoff frequencies 
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn,'bandpass') % Transfer function coefficients of the filter
```

Python script:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

n=2   #Filter_Order
Wn=np.array([0.4,0.6]) # Normalized cutoff frequencies 
b, a = signal.butter(n, Wn, btype='band') #Transfer function coefficients of the filter
```

`a` coefficients in MATLAB:  `1, -5.55e-16, 1.14, -1.66e-16, 0.41`

`a` coefficients in Python: `1, -2.77e-16, 1.14, -1.94e-16, 0.41`

Could it just be a question of precision, since the two different values (the 2nd and 4th) are both  on the order of `10^(-16)`?!

The `b` coefficients are the same on the other hand.

Comment: You get different results using different programming languages and different implementation of the algorithms? I mean, its pretty amazing they are so close.

Comment: *"Could it just be a question of precision, since the two different values (the 2nd and 4th) are both on the order of 10^(-16)?!"* Yes.

Comment: BTW, 1e-16 is essentially 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You machine precision is about `1e-16` (in MATLAB this can be checked easily with [`eps()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), I presume about the same in Python). The 'error' you are dealing with is thus on the order of machine precision, i.e. not actually calculable within fitting precision.

Also of note is that MATLAB ~= Python (or != in Python), thus the implementations of `butter()` on one hand and `signal.butter()` on the other will be slightly different, even if you use *the exact same numbers*, due to the way both languages are translated to machine code.

It rarely matters to have coefficients differing 16 orders of magnitude; the smaller ones would be essentially neglected. In case you do need exact values, consider using either symbolic math, or some kind of Variable Precision Arithmetic ([`vpa()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vpa.html) in MATLAB), but I guess that in your case the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, CPython isn't translated into machine code, although numpy is probably calling routines implemented in compiled, native code